# Converting pairs of input elements into json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

I have a simple ui which has a link that says "add item". When this is clicked, a pair of input boxes appears below it. If it is clicked again, yet another pair appears. I'm trying to think of the best way to generate these elements and turn it into some sort of json array of key value pairs (the first input element in each pair being the key and the second input element being the value).

Right now I just have a counter and I generate the ids using it, such as (in the click event of the "add item" link):

```
$('#features').append('<input id="feature-name-' + self.featureCount + '" type="text" name="asdf" /><a class="delete-feature" data-id="' + self.featureCount + '">Delete</a><input id="feature-description-' + self.featureCount + '" type="text" name="asdf" />');
```

I don't know what to use as the "name" attributes in order to make it easy to create a json array from them.

Comment: Why can't use use the same value as for the *id* attribute?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this without using id attributes.

```
$('#features').append('<div><input type="text" />
<a class="delete-feature" data-id="' + self.featureCount + '">Delete</a><input    type="text" /></div>');
```

And your javascript,

```
var yourArray=[];
$('#yourButton').click(function(){
   $('#features div').each(function(){
      var div=$(this);
      var k=$('input:first',div).val();
      var v=$('input:first',div).next().val();

        yourArray.push({key:k, value: v});

   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what you use for a name attribute, so long as there name and description `name`s are different.  Let's say that these elements are all appended to a form with the id `myform`.  Give each pair its own wrapper object.  Here, I've used a `div`, but a `fieldset` is equally appropriate.

```
$('#features').append(
    '<div class="feature-div">
    '<input id="feature-name-' + self.featureCount + '" type="text" name="asdf" />' +
    '<a class="delete-feature" data-id="' + self.featureCount + '">Delete</a>' +
    '<input id="featurena-description-' + self.featureCount + '" type="text" name="asdf" />' +
    '</div>');
```

Now, it's possible to extract each pair sensibly:

```
var myarray = [];
$('#myform .feature-div').each(function(i, v) {
    myarray.push([
        $('input[name=name]', v).val(), $('input[name=description]', v).val()]);
});
```

Or however you want the data to be presented.